# textFieldShouldBeginEditing not being called in custom class (delegate set)

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a custom class like this:

```
@interface formParser : NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate> {
....
```

and in the .m I create a UITextField element like this:

```
UITextField *ui = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(left, top, width, height)];
[ui setDelegate:self];
[ui setPlaceholder:[dict_elementInfo objectForKey:@"placeholder"]];
[ui setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
[view addSubview:ui];
```

and

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
NSLog(@"should begin");
return NO;
}
```

My problem is that the shouldbegin is never called. When I try this technique on a "normal" UIViewController class it works perfectly, but doing this in my custom object it it never called.. Can anyone figure out why?

My custom class is called as follows:

```
formParser *fParse = [[formParser alloc] init];
UIView *view_formBackground = [fParse viewOfPlist:@"form" initSize:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)];
view_formBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


//add views to main view
[scrollView addSubview:view_formBackground];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Also, in formparser.m the viewofplist is as follows:

```
-(UIView *)viewOfPlist:(NSString *)filename initSize:(CGRect)size
{
ypos_element_left = 40; ypos_element_right = 40;

view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:size];

//load plist
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
rootArray = [dict objectForKey:@"form"];

//loop door alle UI entries in de dict.
for (NSDictionary *dict_UIElement in rootArray)
{
    NSString *UIType = [dict_UIElement objectForKey:@"type"];
    if ([UIType isEqualToString:@"ui_empty"])       [self handle_uiempty:dict_UIElement];
    if ([UIType isEqualToString:@"ui_multiselect"]) [self handle_uimultiselect:dict_UIElement];
    if ([UIType isEqualToString:@"ui_label"])       [self handle_uilabel:dict_UIElement];
    if ([UIType isEqualToString:@"ui_textfield"])   [self handle_uitextfield:dict_UIElement];
    if ([UIType isEqualToString:@"ui_choicefield"]) [self handle_uichoicefield:dict_UIElement];
    if ([UIType isEqualToString:@"ui_calendar"])    [self handle_uicalendar:dict_UIElement];

}


return (view);
```

}

Thanks for answering!

Comment: When you call `[view addSubview:ui];`, what is `view`...and what method is that inside?  (Also, calling `alloc` without `init` is usually a bad idea.)

Comment: "view" is a uiview created in my own "viewofPlist" routine in formparser.m. its returned as view in the routine above... 

I've changed my alloc routine to: formParser *fParse = [[formParser alloc] init] but to no avail... however thanks for that tip ;)

Comment: Edited my question to give you the routine in formparser.m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is one of your allocations falling out of scope and being cleaned up by ARC?

Helpful link on how the responder chain works..

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html

Comment: Thanks for the URL. I have changed formparser from NSObject inheritance to UIView and added canBecomeFirstResponder.. However it is still not working.

Strange fact: 50% of the times any event on the control is fired a get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the debugger (crash)

Comment: Is one of your allocations falling out of scope and being cleaned up by ARC?

Comment: What you may want to do is instead of becoming a delegate, you can set up your own action and target of that object. In formParser.m .. [ui setAction:@selector(myOwnAction:)]; [ui setTarget:self];

Comment: Your comment about ARC made my day! I replaced the var *fParse with a property (nonatomic, retain) and all is working !

If you mark your comment as answer I can accept it ! thanks!